# The answer is in the title

Tags: riddle, word

Take a word for someone that is happy.

Now add 3 letters in front of it, and you've climbed closer to the answer.

Remove the last 3 letters of it, and add 2 in their place, and you're going in the right direction.

Take just the last 2 letters of the word you currently have, and get rid of the rest of the word. Add 1 letter to the end of those 2 letters, and you've got something I might read over coffee.

What am I?

Comment: Is it deliberate that the puzzle doesn't specified where the final "1 more letter" is to be added? (I am expecting that the answer is yes; but if e.g. it was meant to be obvious that it goes at the end, or something like that, you might want to make it explicit.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan thanks for reminding me. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: The edit still leaves it ambiguous where the new letter goes. But did I imagine an intermediate version that made it explicit?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I'm not really sure how to phrase this, but what I'm trying to say is: take the last two letters of the word that was formed. Get rid of the rest of the word and keep just those two letters. Add 1 more letter to those 2 letters. I've added an edit; could you take a look and see if this clarifies the issue?

Comment: Yup, perfectly clear now.

Comment: What does "The answer is in the title" mean?

Comment: @NL628 It means that by analysing the words that compose the title, you can get an indirect hint as to what the answer is.

Comment: Sorry, I meant which title. Did you mean the title "The answer is in the title"?

Comment: @NL628 oh, yes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be

> the word ”The”

The answer is in the title.

> So it is. Twice.

The word chain: (copypaste wont work on my phone)

> Gay (happy)
>  Norgay (climbed Everest with Hillary)
>  North (direction)
>  The (you might read ”an article” over coffee) (Thanks, Gareth)

Comment: You got the first three clues right, but your reasoning for the last clue is a bit off, so your answer is very close but incorrect.

Comment: @fi12 do you mean that the answer is another word with those two letters at the beginning, or that you require a better reasoning for the last step? (I have a handful of those, but would rather skip the ”guess which one I’m thinking” game)

Comment: No, "the" is right. But you wouldn't read "the" over coffee, you'd read something else. What is that thing?

Comment: Well, there are about 2 million newspapers with a The in their name.

Comment: I think you've missed my point. I'm not looking for a specific newspaper.

Comment: You can probably see why I don’t like this game. No matter how fitting my answer, it will be correct only if I happen, by pure chance, to guess exactly the thing you were thinking about. If you think the reasoning is very spectacularly awesome and mission critical to the extreme, I’m very happy to wait for someone else to guess it. Otherwise, you are most welcome to just spill it :-)

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I think I'll keep the puzzle open a bit longer. The correct answer would make a little more sense for the last clue as to something that you would actually read over coffee, as opposed to being a word like "the", although you did manage to figure out the rest of the clues quite easily. Did you manage to reverse engineer the puzzle or did you happen to solve it in the order I described?

Comment: @fi12, that’s quite ok. I managed to get a lock on the first two words rather quickly, since the clues had very little ”give” in them. (Meaning that it was pretty clear if a word pair worked or not. Always a very nice feature in a good clue.) From there, I just worked forward, since there weren’t many forks in the road, trying to reach anything that would match the title clue.

Comment: Bass I think @fi12 may be refereing to "the news" (or "the headlines") in general, and not a specific newspaper.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I guess I'm not good at making my clues unambiguous :-). That's a good guess, but it's not what I'm looking for either. "The news" isn't in the title. Think less about the word "the", and more about what the word "the" actually *is*.

Comment: I think the word fi12 is looking for is probably *article*.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan oo, that’s definite(ly) clever!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan That's correct!